# Main class got deleted in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I accidentally deleted Main class in intelliJ. How do I find it now? I refactored it in a class in my package and then deleted that class.

Comment: [Accidentally deleted file, can I recover from IDEA's Local VCS](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206328679-Accidentally-deleted-file-can-I-recover-from-IDEA-s-Local-VCS-)

Answer (score 0):

Try right click on the folder -> Local history, your file should be there with all changes you have done. See the official [documentation page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.1/show-history-for-folder-dialog.html?utm_campaign=IU&utm_content=2020.1&utm_medium=link&utm_source=product) for more information about this feature.